# Next js 13 cache:'no-store' is throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js, frontend

Take a look at this code

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/posts', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization:
        'Bearer 40742660cb44bedd348f8e69024c8f591f80124111fcfa2f1ec612f63e22be4d55ed429b4497887812da5e385f02a2b27e352551284c2c9793c33efd620c86f34058504b0ed9c76a13a6c7313d3b39826748ad0a15f5dab8ba85dbefba2ef29ab52290f98ca73a4359c6988063e96f0f5f68dafd25aac04f865e91dd9515915a',
    },
  })
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}
export default async function page() {
  const result = await getData()
  console.log(result)
  return <div>page</div>
}
```

this code is fetching me some posts from my strapi backend. but the problem is it just returns the same or cached result every time even if the post changes on frontend and backend. But as I add `cache:'no-store'` or `cache:'no-cache'` or even `revalidate:0`  option it goes to the error and shows `failed to fetch data`

Answer (score 0):

In my project I am using revalidate and it works.  Where are you passing these options?

My code example.

```
import qs from "qs";
import { getStrapiURL } from "./api-helpers";

export async function fetchAPI(
  path: string,
  urlParamsObject = {},
  options = {}
) {
  try {
    // Merge default and user options
    const mergedOptions = {
      next: { revalidate: 60 },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      ...options,
    };

    // Build request URL
    const queryString = qs.stringify(urlParamsObject);
    const requestUrl = `${getStrapiURL(
      `/api${path}${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ""}`
    )}`;

    // Trigger API call
    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, mergedOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error(`Please check if your server is running and you set all the required tokens.`);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

You can checkout the whole project [here](https://github.com/strapi/nextjs-corporate-starter)

Comment: passing it like this :
 const res=await fetch(url,
{ cache: 'no-cache' },
{
method:'GET',
 headers:{}
}
)

Comment: ok i think what the problem is I am doing it this way 
const res=await fetch(Url , {cache goes here},{method and headers go here})
but instead I should do it like this 
const res=awiat fetch(URL, { {cache goes here},{method and headers go here}}

Comment: it is working with the second option, but the thing is I have used it over multiple places and the first approach is working fine